# how can I customise keyboard in natviescript angular app

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am using keyboardType="phone" how can I customise keyboard in ios and android in Nativescript angular app how to disable + * # it should be only number input from keyboard no special character and sign

[image: ios - keyboardType="phone"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as [these changes](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/8190) are released, you'll be able to use `keyboardType=integer` to get a keyboard that only shows numbers, it will look like this:

[image]

Comment: if I use keyboardType=number above shown keypad is not coming  ?  numbersAndPunctuation keypad coming for Nativescript Angular app

Comment: @Radhesham You are correct. There is an issue [about this in the GitHub repository](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3303). `keyboardType=integer` will solve your problem, but hasn't been released yet.